# The diagonals of a trapezoid are perpendicular and have lengths 8 and 10. Find the length of the median of the trapezoid.

Tags: geometry

The diagonals of a trapezoid are perpendicular and have lengths 8 and 10. Find the length of the median of the trapezoid.

It this possible without a rhombus?

Comment: If we can find the height of the trapezoid, then the median follows easily, but ...

Answer (score 5):

Let $ABCD$ a trapezoid such that $FG$ is its median,
$AC$ and $DB$ are perpendicular, $DC=w$, $AB =z$, $AC=8$ and $DB=10$.

Let $r$ such that $r \parallel  AC$ and $D \in r$.

Let $s$ such that  $A \in s$ and $B \in s$.

Let point $E$ such that $\{E\} =r \cap s$. See the figure below:

[image]

It follows that:
$$DE=CA=8,$$
$$EA=w,$$
$$FG = \frac{w+z}{2} \quad (1)$$
and
$$DE \perp DB.$$
Using the Pythagorean Theorem in $\triangle EDB$, we get:
$$w+z= \sqrt{164} = 2 \sqrt{41}.$$
From $(1)$ we get:
$$FG= \sqrt{41}.$$
Therefore it is possible to determine $FG$ without assuming a rhombus.

Answer (score 1):

Trapezoid can never be a rhombus - or more generally a parallelogram - because a trapezoid, by definition, can only have one set of parallel sides (also called bases).

Comment: While you may have a point about trapezoids being distinguished by definition from rhombi, there is still a problem in the Question that you did not address.  Answering a two year old Question should emphasize thoroughness in presentation rather than brevity.