# Trapezoid With Perpendicular Diagonals

Tags: geometry

The diagonals of a trapezoid are perpendicular and have lengths 8 and 10. Find the length of the median of the trapezoid.

I have no idea about this problem except assuming that the trpezoid is a rhombus.  This is a duplicate, but the solution on [The diagonals of a trapezoid are perpendicular and have lengths 8 and 10. Find the length of the median of the trapezoid.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919956/the-diagonals-of-a-trapezoid-are-perpendicular-and-have-lengths-8-and-10-find-t) is a little bit too advanced for me.  Can anyone solve this using a simpler method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the diagonals cut themselves in four segments with lengths $a,b,c,d$, in such a way that $b+d=10,a+c=8$ and the right triangle with legs $a,b$ is similar to the right triangle with legs $c,d$, so that $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{d}{c}$ or, equivalently, $ad=bc$. That leads to the equation:
$$ a(10-b)=b(8-a) $$
that is equivalent to $10a=8b$, hence $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{d}{c}=\frac{5}{4}$. So we have that all the trapezoids with perpendicular diagonals such that $a=x,\,b=\frac{5}{4}x,\,c=y,\,d=\frac{5}{4}y,\,x+y=8$ meet the given constraints. For such trapezoids, the bases have length
$$ \frac{x}{4}\sqrt{41},\qquad \frac{y}{4}\sqrt{41} $$
by the Pythagorean theorem, hence the "median" has length
$$ \frac{x+y}{8}\sqrt{41} = \color{red}{\sqrt{41}}.$$

In general, if a trapezoid has perpendicular diagonals with length $\ell_1,\ell_2$, the segment joining the midpoints of the diagonal sides has length $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\ell_1^2+\ell_2}$. Here it comes a proof (almost) without words: the red segments have the same length.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, Jack D'Aurizio!

Comment: @MathMuse: you are always welcome.